# Sidebar navigation menu is disappeared?

Tags: master-page, global-navigation

There was sidebar navigation with seattle. But now it is disappeared.It is default page when i opened new subsite.[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81643/discussion-on-question-by-f-gulay-sidebar-navigation-menu-is-disappeared).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shot in the dark here. but is it possible you clicked on the collapse button? See my screenshot.

The reason I propose is this I notice from your screenshot the SUITE bar is missing. Which suggests that you clicked on the collapse button. Clicking on it again will cause both the suite bar and the left hand navigation to show. It is located on the top right corner of the screen.

[image]

Comment: happens most of the times

Comment: wooow ! it works , so how does it happen ?